# tag [wave] wiki doesn't correspond to its main usage

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki

I was browsing the [wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wave) tag, due to some work related stuff, and just by accident I read the tag description.

> WAVE acronym for Wireless Access in Vehicular Environments

But the tag is mostly used in relation to wave - Python module used to manipulate `.wav` files or the `wave` file format.

Should I just edit the wiki of this tag, or a new tag should be created ex. [python-wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-wave)?

Comment: That's pretty silly, just edit the tag wiki.   Include a recommendation to use the [wav] tag instead.

Comment: I've just retagged those outliers to [tag:802.11p] (altough I'm not sure whether an own tag is warranted for them at all)

Comment: What was the final answer? 'wave' is only a four-letter word, so the chance of both ambiguity and name collision is incredibly high, also confusion with .WAV files. We don't want a tag for every library from every language, hence [wave] should not exist as a tag for a Python library.  As to 'Wireless Access in Vehicular Environments', I never heard the acronym, but again 'wave' is very ambiguous and non-self-explanatory. If you must create a tag (and I'm not saying it needs one, this isn't my area), how about 'vehicular-wireless'? Meanwhile, the tag [wave] should be deleted.